# I want to display only Books from Books location in Firebase Realtime database filtering by child "discipline" obtained from Lecturers location

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display only Books from Books location in Firebase Realtime database filtering by child "discipline" obtained from Lecturers location.

Code to display the books in Recycler Adapter

```
public class LecturerBooks extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LecturerBookAdapter lecturerBookAdapter;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;
    DatabaseReference dbRef;
    DatabaseReference userRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lecturer_books);

        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);    

        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        authListener = mAuth -> {
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user == null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LecturerBooks.this, LecturerLogin.class));
                finish();
            }
            else {
                String mail=user.getEmail();
                userRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Lecturers");
                userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            if (Objects.equals(ds.child("email").getValue(), mail)) {

                                String program = ds.child("discipline").getValue(String.class);
                                dbRef = (DatabaseReference) FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Books");
                                dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                        if(Objects.equals(snapshot.child("discipline").getValue(), program))
                                        {    
                                                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(LecturerBooks.this));

                                                FirebaseRecyclerOptions<BookModel> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<BookModel>()
                                                        .setQuery(dbRef, BookModel.class)
                                                        .build();

                                                lecturerBookAdapter = new LecturerBookAdapter(options);
                                                recyclerView.setAdapter(lecturerBookAdapter);

                                                lecturerBookAdapter.startListening();
                                        }    
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {    
                                    }
                                });   
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    }
                });
            }
        };    
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
        //lecturerBookAdapter.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (authListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authListener);
        }
        //lecturerBookAdapter.stopListening();
    }
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(LecturerBooks.this,LecturerMain.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Firebase Recycler view is not displaying filtered data.

Books location

[image: firebase Books location]

Lecturer location in firebase

[image: Lecturer location in firebase]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only load the books for a specific discipline, you can [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) to order and filter the data:

```
String program = ds.child("discipline").getValue(String.class);
dbRef = (DatabaseReference) FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Books");
Query query = dbRef.orderByChild("discipline").equalTo(program);
dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  ...
```

Don't forget to [define an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) on `discipline` in your database's rules, to ensure the query can be performed on the server.